# Math.Round() decimal c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a `TimeSpan`, `ts`.

When I use `Math.Round(ts.TotalHours,2)` it's returning `3,3` and that is correct.

I want to format my decimal to `3,33 -> 3,5`

Like this:

```
3 hours = 3,0
3 hours and 10 minutes = 3,25
3 hours and 20 minutes = 3,5
3 hours and 35 minutes = 3,75
3 hours and 55 minutes = 4
```

Does any one have a good idea?

Comment: Use the overload that takes a rounding mode.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to round the the nearest 0.25 you can simply multiply with 4, round, and divide by 4.

```
public static decimal RoundToQuarter(decimal x)
{
  return Math.Round(x*4)/4;
}
```

You should also think about which `MidPointRounding` behavior you want. i.e. what happens with values like `1/8` or `3/8`. Default is round-to-even, where `1/8` becomes `0`, and `3/8` becomes `0.5`.